# Having trouble understanding an rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have an assignment which involves writing code in ruby to meet the requirements of specific rspec tests, but I'm really struggling to understand this one in particular:

```
it "should check for a winner with top row" do
            @game.winner = nil
            @game.clearmatrix
            @game.setmatrixvalue(0,  "0")
            @game.setmatrixvalue(1,  "0")
            @game.setmatrixvalue(2,  "0")
            @game.checkwinner.should == check_winner && @game.winner.should_not == nil
        end
```

The programme is going to be a noughts & crosses (tic tac toe?) game, with the above test specifically checking if someone has all 3 spaces in the top row (there are various other tests to check the other combinations).

Now, I assume that I should create a new method called winner, which should have some default value?

I'm confused as to why I would want to call clearmatrix as part of the checkwinner method... Surely if I clear the matrix then the programme won't be able to check if there's a winner?

The last line of the test is the main part that I'm really struggling to understand though. I take it that I need to have an if statement in checkwinner which returns true if all 3 spaces are the same, but what is check_winner? Should it be another method? And why would I set winner = nil and then need winner to not be nil?

This is what I have so far for the other tests (all passing) in case it helps:

```
def start
            #Calls method to display appropriate messages.
            messages
        end

        def created_by
            return "myname"
        end

        def student_id
            return mystudentid #this is an integer
        end

        def messages
            @output.puts "Welcome to Noughts and Crosses!"
            @output.puts "Created by:Stephen Mitchell"
            @output.puts "Starting game..."
            @output.puts "Player 1: 0 and Player 2: 1"
        end

        def setplayer1
            @player1 = 0
        end

        def setplayer2
            @player2 = 1
        end

        def clearmatrix
            @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
        end

        def getmatrixvalue(n)
            @matrix[n]
        end

        def setmatrixvalue(i, v)
            i = 1
            v = "0"
            @matrix[i] = "0"
        end

        def displaykey(matrix)
            @matrix = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
            @output.puts "Table key:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
        end

        def displaymatrix
            @matrix = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
            @output.puts "Table status:\n|#{matrix[0]}|#{matrix[1]}|#{matrix[2]}|\n|#{matrix[3]}|#{matrix[4]}|#{matrix[5]}|\n|#{matrix[6]}|#{matrix[7]}|#{matrix[8]}|\n"
        end

        def finish
            @output.puts "Finishing game..."
        end

        def displaymenu
            @output.puts "Menu: (1)Start | (2)New | (9)Exit\n"
        end

        def checkwinner
        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test you are setting manually cells values.
In your spec you can set

```
check_winner = "0"
```

In the Game class the `checkwinner` method can be something like this:

```
def checkwinner
  if (matrix[0] == matrix[1]) && (matrix[1] == matrix[2])
    matrix[0]
  elsif # conditions for all other win cases
  end
end
```

The `clearmatrix` method simply clears your game field before its manual setup.